# После установки дистрибутива линукс на экране вылазит графический артефакт

Tags: debian, графика

Пробовал устанавливать различные дистрибутивы. Карта gtx660 geforce. [image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у меня было это - поменял диск (HDD) и эта шляпа пропала

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, проблема в самой видеокарте или в драйверах к ней. Попробуйте разные версии драйвера и проверьте саму видеокарту (Можете проверить ее на Windows). Надеюсь, подсказал вам что-то стоящее.

Comment: у меня один в один было - точно как на скрине, я заваливал форум ubuntu и toster скринами ..все блин логи просили - тупо - а кк я решил проблему - прочитайте мой комментрий выше

Comment: @MaximLensky ну, может быть и поможет